# Keep getting KeyError: 'main' despite code working elsewhere

Tags: python, json, url

I'm trying to extract data out of a json concerning several cities weather patterns using a for loop and input said data into the dataframe df_cities:

```
units = 'imperial'
params = {'appid': api_key,
         'units': units}

for index, row in df_cities.iterrows():    
    base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
    city = row['Name']
    params['q'] = f'{city}'
    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params).json()

    df_cities.loc[index, 'Temperature'] = response['main']['temp']
    df_cities.loc[index, 'Humidity'] = response['main']['humidity']
    df_cities.loc[index, 'Cloudiness'] = response['main']['temp']
    df_cities.loc[index, 'Windspeed'] = response['wind']['speed']
```

However, no matter what way I structure the loop, I keep getting a KeyError: 'main'. But if I perform response['main]['temp'] outside the loop, I get my desired result:

```
citys = 'Chicago'
units = 'imperial'
url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
query_url = f'{url}appid={api_key}&q={citys}&units={units}'
response = requests.get(query_url).json()

response['main']['temp']
```

> 39.33

Why isn't python recognizing the json inside the loop?

Comment: Make sure to print out the JSON you're actually getting. Maybe you're being rate-limited.

Comment: *Saying this here as I cannot comment* As kindall said, you might be rate-limited, and should check you actually received the JSON, given that you would probably not get any errors if you didn't. How many cities are there in `df_cities`? Assuming you're using the free pricing for openweathermap, you cannot make more than 60 requests in a minute, which you probably exceeds if you do not slow down your for loop (if it does iterate on more than 60 cities).

Answer (score 0):

The response for Chicago does contain the `main` key, but at some point your `df_cities.iterrows()` loop produces some other city that does not have the `main` key in its response.

You can check for the presence of `main` before trying to access it:

```
if 'main' in response:
    df_cities.loc[index, 'Temperature'] = response['main']['temp']
    df_cities.loc[index, 'Humidity'] = response['main']['humidity']
    df_cities.loc[index, 'Cloudiness'] = response['main']['temp']
    df_cities.loc[index, 'Windspeed'] = response['wind']['speed']
else:
    print('main key not in response JSON for city %s' % city)
```

Comment: All the results come out as 'main key not in ...' If I look at the list of cities and just plug in any individual city as part of the url, then I can get the result despite the same city having not have worked in the for-loop